# If a nested element fires an event, dont let the container handle it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div that contains another div.
If the user clicks the inner div I only want the eventhandler attached to this element get executed. Right now first the eventhandler of the inner element and then that of the outer element gets executed. Is there a way to change this?

```
    <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Demo</title>
  </head>
  <body>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#containerElement").click(function(event){
         alert("This comes from container");
       });

      $("#innerElement").click(function(event){
         alert("This comes from inner element");
       });
     });
   </script>


   <div id="containerElement" >
   This is the container
     <div id="innerElement" >
   This is the inner element


   </div>

   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Too easy question it seems. 2 minutes and 4 almost identical answers ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could [stop the propagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/):

```
$("#innerElement").click(function(event){
    alert("This comes from inner element");
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `event.stopPropagation();`

```
$("#innerElement").click(function(event){
    alert("This comes from inner element");
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Returning `false` from the handler will prevent bubbling (among other things):

```
$("#innerElement").click(function(event){
     alert("This comes from container");
     return false;
});
```

Comment: Did you mean to add `return false;` to `#innerElement`? Your code as-is will still fire the click event for the containing element.

Answer (score 0):

Add `event.stopPropagation()` to your innerElement event handler. See the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) for more info.

```
$("#innerElement").click(function(event){
    alert("This comes from inner element");
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As above:

http://jsbin.com/avikol/2/

Comment: I withdraw. Didn't saw the closing tags