# Mouseout fires on nested element, I only want it to fire when it leaves the container

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript: Multiple mouseout events triggered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705182/javascript-multiple-mouseout-events-triggered)

I keep having an issue where I'm looking to see when my mouse exits a container, and the event is fired when I hover over an element contained within the container. I know that jQuery has fixed this problem with the `.hover` function, but I don't want to use an entire library to solve a single problem. How do I do this in JavaScript?

My question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9220081/if-a-nested-element-fires-an-event-dont-let-the-container-handle-it), but I'm not using jQuery.

Comment: Check the `event.target`

Comment: Can you provide a working (or not working as the case may be) example of what you've tried?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.stopPropagation

Comment: @jbabey you'd need to attach an event listener to all children of the container you're interested in. Not always feasible.

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_mouse.html will help you.

Comment: @jbabey: This does not necessarily help. The `mouseout` event is also triggered when you move over/into a child. Stopping event propagation does not help in this case (I assume thats what you meant).

Comment: i found teh codez: http://cvmlrobotics.blogspot.com/2012/10/javascript-cross-browser-implementation.html

Comment: @FelixKling - thanks, that's the link I was looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Felix had the right answer with his first link.  To quote from the [article](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_mouse.html) ...

> Another show stopper is that when you move the mouse into the layer,
>   and then onto a link, browsers register a mouseout event on the layer!
>   It doesn't make much sense to me (the mouse is still in the layer),
>   but all browsers agree on this one.
>
> So how do we reject any mouseout that does not take place when the
>   mouse actually leaves the layer?

```
function doSomething(e) {
if (!e) var e = window.event;
var tg = (window.event) ? e.srcElement : e.target;
if (tg.nodeName != 'DIV') return;
var reltg = (e.relatedTarget) ? e.relatedTarget : e.toElement;
while (reltg != tg && reltg.nodeName != 'BODY')
    reltg= reltg.parentNode
if (reltg== tg) return;
// Mouseout took place when mouse actually left layer
// Handle event
}
```

> First get the event target, ie. the element the mouse moved out of. If
>   the target is not the DIV (layer), end the function immediately, since
>   the mouse has certainly not left the layer.
>
> If the target is the layer, we're still not sure if the mouse left the
>   layer or entered a link within the layer. Therefore we're going to
>   check the relatedTarget/toElement of the event, ie. the element the
>   mouse moved to.
>
> We read out this element, and then we're going to move upwards through
>   the DOM tree until we either encounter the target of the event (ie.
>   the DIV), or the body element.
>
> If we encounter the target the mouse moves towards a child element of
>   the layer, so the mouse has not actually left the layer. We stop the
>   function.
>
> When the function has survived all these checks we're certain that the
>   mouse has actually left the layer and we can take appropriate action
>   (usually making the layer invisible).

Comment: Yeah, this is pretty similar to what I ended up using.